# Numbering points per polygon group with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, expression, overlay

In QGIS, I have a point and a polygon layer. I want to number the points ascending from left to right (from smallest to highest x-coordinate value - West to East). However, counting should be made separately for each group of polygons with a common attribute value.

The screenshot shows the setting: all points inside polygons with value = 1 are considered together and should be counted from 1 to N, starting with the leftmost and proceeding to the right. Points inside polygons with value = 2 should also start from 1 to N, left to right, points in polygons = 3 as well and so on.

How to achieve that using QGIS expressions?

[image]

Comment: I'm open to any kind of solution (also a virtual layer  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a solution using the expression, it may seem a bit lamer.

Let's assume there are two layers: a point *'random_points_test'* and a polygon *'poly_test'* respectively, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Use the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) to get `"id"`s from polygons

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Proceed with the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) geoalgorithm for the result from the *Step 1* with the following settings:

[image: step_2_1]

`"id"`s from polygons was used as *'Group values by [optional]'*

and get the output

[image: result]

Comment: Indeed, works nice! Even if there are a few steps more to do and new layers will be created, I learned something new, namely the `Add autoincremental field` tool. So I will see if there will be some other answers and if not, will come back to accept you answer (always better than accepting an own answer). If I forget, you might remember me.

Comment: I think there are better answers, mine is just old school. Let's see :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression (explanation see below):

```
to_int(
    array_find (
        array_sort (
            array_agg( 
                x(
                    geometry (
                        get_feature_by_id (
                            @layer,
                            $id
                ))), 
                group_by:= array_first (
                    overlay_within( 
                        'poly', 
                        class
        ))))
        , $x
    )+1
)
```

Explanation:

1. Lines 5 to 10: get the x-coordinate values of the points contained in the layer.
2. Lines 4 to 15: Create an array (`array_agg`) of these x-values for all points, but group them by an attribute `class` from the polygon-layer - so the array contains only points that are in the same group (=are within one of the polygons (`overlay_within`) with the same value for the attribute `class`).
3. Lines 3 to 16: sort (`array_sort`) this array in ascending order, thus smallest x-coordinate value at the beginning.
4. Line 1 to last line: get the x-coordinate value of the current point feature (`$x`) and look in the array (`array_find`) at which position (index) it is. Add 1 (`+1`) as the index returns `0` for the first element. Optional: convert to integer (`to_int`, for use in a concatenated string).

*Screenshot: the expression in action to create a dynamic label with the counting (after the dot), together with an additional information before the dot for the polygon each point lies within:*
[image]

Comment: You can also use `$x` instead of `x($geometry)`

Comment: @Taras - of course, you're completely right. Sometimes, caring about more complicated problems, you forget about the very simple things. So I'll edit the question to use this easier way to do that. Thank... ups, not allowed here ;-)

Comment: How do you get the information in which polygon (id or name) the point lies?

Comment: Using `overlay_within()` function

Comment: Found a solution to get the polygon id: `attribute(get_feature_by_id('layer_name_polygons',
array_find( array_foreach( aggregate ( 'layer_name_polygons', 'array_agg', $geometry ), intersects($geometry, @element) ), '1') ),'id')`