# Points to Path - creating an expression to group required points

Tags: qgis

Given two almost parallel lines where points have been added every 5.4m, I want to create a polygon using the point that is on the BL to the BR, to the next one up on the Right to the Next one up on the Left.

[image]

So

- a. 129---0 to 1---0 to 2---5.4 to 130---5.4 to 129---0
- b. 130---5.4 to 2--5.4 to 3---10.8 to 131---10.8 to 130---5.4

etc

How can I group these via the Path Group Expression in the Points to Path tool?

I hope there's some logic we can use as https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409438/2891

It is basically

- a. Group based on equal distance and the point that is with a 5.5m
  buffer of these points
- b. As the line could be oriented E-W or W-E we    can't use the x
  value alone but need to have a sorted ID that the    point to path
  can use. I am not sure how to do this?