QGIS sequential numbering of points within polygons
I'm trying to add points within polygons and each point will get a sequential number based on the other points within the same polygon. In the point layer there is a boundary_id field which has a value that corresponds to the uuid of the polygon that the point intersects. The field with the sequential numbering is pt_num. I currently have the following expression in the default value of the pt_num field:
coalesce(
    aggregate(
    layer:='points',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="pt_num",
    filter:= "boundary_id" = attribute(@parent,'boundary_id')) +1, 1
            )

I use the coalsece function to generate a 1 value for the first point in the polygon. The feature looks like it should work. If I highlight different features in the 'Preview' of the expression builder, it will show the next highest value depending on which polygon the highlighted feature is in. However, when I actually add points in the project, all of the features get a value of 1.


Something like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409438/88814 Not sure which one is the "first", "second" etc. point in your understanding, based on what criteria?
